# how do i handle loading javascript with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

This might have been asked somewhere else but I can't seem to find it.

I have a website that I am attempting to use history.js & ajax for the navigation.

The javascript files are fired by a `$(document).ready`. When you load a javascript file twice both the original javascript file and the new javascript file are being called.

What is the best way to go about loading javascript files to stop this?

Comment: Why are you loading the same file twice?

Comment: Basically if you navigate away from a page and then back to it, it would load the javascript files again to fire on the original page. Would it be a better idea to not load those javascript files and have an alternative way of calling them?